# Lightning component doesn't refresh on second search

Tags: lightning-aura-components, aura-if

I am trying to load a Google map VF page in my lightning component and display leads based on city searched. The component loads properly with the leads on first search but on the second search the component doesn't refreshes and displays old records

Here's the piece of code-

```
<aura:if isTrue="{!and(v.lead.length > 0, v.acc.length == 0) }">
   <c:GoogleMap id="GoogleMap" lat="{!v.lat}"  long="{!v.long}" mapOptions="{!v.mapOptions}" mapOptionsCenter="{!v.mapOptionsCenter}" mapData="{!v.mapData}" />
 </aura:if>
```

Attribute holding the search string i.e Place-

```
<aura:attribute name="place" type="String"/>
```

Is it because the lead.length > 0 is true in second case as well so the component doesn't reloads. How should I achieve this then. Appreciate any help here! Thanks

Comment: any reason why you are not  using the [lightning:map](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:map/example) component?

Comment: I don't think there is enough code context here to provide an answer. Please show how the search is initiated.

Comment: If the condition always evaluates to true, the contents within `aura:if` will not be re-rendered.

Comment: @glls- Lightning:map is just for displaying records. I want more customisations. e.g actions on the map marker, a search bar on map to search places etc

Comment: @JayantDas- How can I render the same component with different values then

Comment: How is the search attribute populated?

Comment: Its from the VF page and I am listening it in the component using event.    <aura:handler name="setPlace" event="c:SendPlace" action="{!c.setAttributeValue}"/>

Comment: It may be better to not use an if condition and dynamically create the map component instead.

Comment: I am not able to figure out how is your `place` attribute related to `GoogleMap` component. As how is this passed to the component to be able to render the component?